# Wrap right div around left div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to wrap my right div around my left, in an inverse moon shape? Here's what it looks like right now.

[image: current div]

What I want to do is have the red block wrap around the rounder corners of the black block. Here is the current HTML/CSS code, I apologize if the CSS code is a little "messy" as i have been experimented different codes.

HTML

```
<div class="container full-width">
  <div class="row proj">
    <div class="col-md-8 full-width">          
      <div class="content">          
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 full-width">          
      <div class="options">
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 .content { 
    margin-top: 75px;
    position: relative;
    width: 70vw;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 90vh;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 0 50vw 50vw 0;   
}

.options {  
    margin-top: 75px;
    position: relative;
    width: 30vw;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 90vh;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: red;  
}

.container .full-width{ 
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;    
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Answer Found, thanks for the help, so had to tweak the code a bit from your posted code, it looks like this now.

```
.content { 
   margin-top: 75px;
    width: 30vw;
    height: 90vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 0 50vw 50vw 0;   
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;     
}

.options {  
    margin-top: 75px;
    margin-left:3%;
    position:relative;
    float:right;
    width: 30vw;
    height: 90vh;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: red;      
}

.container .full-width{ 
    position: absolute;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;

}
```

and the final result looks like this, will tweak the positioning some more but the result is what i wanted, thanks again.

[image: current div]

**UPDATE 2**

Ok, had to make another edit, for some reason I had to float them both left. OTherwise if i kept the red div float right and tried to expand its width, it would expand to the left, any idea why? current code:

```
.content { 
   margin-top: 75px;
    width: 44vw;
    height: 90vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 0 50vw 50vw 0;   
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;     
}

.options {  
    margin-top: 75px;
    margin-left:20%;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width: 50vw;
    height: 90vh;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: red;      
}

.container .full-width{ 
    position: absolute;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use position:relative; for `content` and position:absolute; for `options`

```css
 .content { 
    width: 30vw;
    height: 90vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 0 50vw 50vw 0;   
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
}

.options {  
    margin-left:3%;
    position:absolute;
    float:right;
    width: 30vw;
    height: 90vh;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: red;  
}
```

```html
<div class="container full-width">
      <div class="row proj">
        <div class="col-md-8 full-width">          
          <div class="content">          
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 full-width">          
          <div class="options">
          </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
```

Comment: hmm this does not produce the code snippet showed in your answer for me. Inputting your code my red div disappears completely , if i remove overflow-x from .contect .fullwidth I will have the same picture as posted on my question except the red block becomes a thing red line at the top

Comment: Doing a bit of research it seems that absolute positioning and bootstrap need some work around. I will see what I can find out

Comment: Ok i got it, had to tweak your code just a little, appreciate the help